# python: 'rand' is not defined, using random in a class

Tags: python, class, random, module

I'm having trouble using the random module, because I'm using the randint in a class, it doesn't seem to be able to access the random module. How should this be approached?

```
from random import random

class Pursuer():
    X_tally = 0
    Y_tally = 0

    def __init__(self):     


    def roll_pursue_type(self):
        self.pursue_dice = rand.randint(1,100)
        print(self.pursue_dice)
```

Traceback: line 12, in roll_pursue_type
    self.pursue_dice = rand.randint(1,100)
NameError: name 'rand' is not defined

Comment: `from random import randint self.pursue_dice = randint(1,100)` there is no such thing as rand

Comment: use 
import random as rand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module is called `random`, not `rand`, but you didn't import it correctly:

```
# Import the *module*, not the function
import random

# Use the correct name in your method
self.pursue_dice = random.randint(1,100)
```

The statement `from random import random` only imports a reference to the [`random.random()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random), not the module itself. You are trying to use a *different* function on that module, so it is easier to import the whole module object instead.

You *can* import the module under another name too:

```
# Still importing the *module*, not the function, but renaming it
import random as rand

# using the new name in your method
self.pursue_dice = rand.randint(1,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rand from numpy:

```
from numpy.random import rand
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `random`, not `rand` (plus, you only have imported the random function from the random module)

So either you use `import random` then `random.randint()`, or you can rename random when importing:

```
import random as rand
```

Answer (score 0):

import random as rand

self.pursue_dice = rand.randint(1,100)

just use python as operator random as rand

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
data = {i : np.random.randn() for i in range(7)}
data
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_